# Run program as a (linux style) foreground terminal process on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, cmd

does anyone know how to produce a similar result?(essentially tying the windows terminal to the open program)

For example, when you run "`emacs`" in bash (or another linux terminal) it will produce an output into the open terminal until the program is terminated (or silenced with `emacs &`)

I want to be able to reproduce this effect on windows, but have no idea how, running `start`(and similar commands) will only run the program in a new window, with a hidden command line, detached from the cmd line process.

Comment: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/

Comment: I think i've not explained this clearly enough - im after the debug/run output that linux normally dumps into the active terminal, not how to run cygwin or emacs

Comment: `PROGRAM.EXE > OUTPUT.TXT` will save the output of your program in a file called `OUTPUT.TXT`

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Close enough to it yeah! It will do for now, but i was kind of hoping of having it paste into the open terminal window, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `/B` flag:

```
start /B myprogram
```

(Of course, this will only work with programs that actually use the console.  If the program doesn't generate console output, this won't magically make it do so.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by first installing Cygwin and then running emacs from Cygwin.

Cygwin is a collection of tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

try typing `edit` into a windows command shell, it's actually a better program than notepad. there are versions of vi, emacs, for windows and dos, you could try any of them.

ftp://ftp.delorie.com/pub/djgpp/current/v2gnu/

http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc